# Compiling a set of NSIS scripts using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, file, compilation, nsis

I have a script having dependencies to two other scripts.  I'm using Eclipse as my NSIS editor. whenever I have changes to script3, I have to compile script1 and script2 first. And I do it manually. Other than creating a batch file, is there a way you could tell Eclipse that everytime you compile script3, it has to compile script1 and script2 first?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you using [EclipseNSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/EclipseNSIS_-_NSIS_plugin_for_Eclipse)?

[image]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/mediawiki/images/c/c8/Eclipsensis1.gif))</sub>

Comment: So, how do you do it then? I checked the options for creating a project, but I can't find any option/settings that could compile the whole project.